# How to make edges unique and to quantify them without out-of-memory error

Tags: arangodb

I've created an edge collection with about 16 Mio edges. The edges are not unique, means there are more than one edge from vertex a to vertex b. The edge collection size is about 2.4 GB data and has 1.6 GB edge index size. I am using a computer with 16 GB RAM (and additionally, 16 BG swap space).

Now I try to calculate unique edges (between each couple of vertex a-b) with a statement like this one:

```
FOR wf IN DeWritesWith
        COLLECT from = wf._from, to = wf._to WITH COUNT INTO res
        INSERT { "_from": from, "_to": to, "type": "writesWith", "numArticles": res } INTO DeWritesWithAggregated
// Does also lead to out-of-memory error:        
//        RETURN { "_from": from, "_to": to, "type": "writesWith", "numArticles": res }
```

My Problem: I always run out-of-memory (32 GB RAM). As the problem also occures when I do not want to write the result, I assume it is not a problem of huge write transaction logs.
Is this normal, and can I optimize the AQL somehow? I am hoping for a solution as I think this scenario is a more generic usage scenario in graphs ...

Comment: We are currently looking into ways for optimizing the `COLLECT`. The `COLLECT` currently is expensive because it will fully sort the collection in the above case (no sorted index present on `_from` or `_to`, just the unsorted edge index). Probably the sort can be optimized away in some cases, and this is what we are currently investigating. Will report progress here if any.

Comment: Sounds good. And that fits to my latest test in which I duplicated the _from,_to into additional attributes, made a split-index onto it and calculated it then ... took 60 seconds. That was real good performance, esp. in comparison to mem-out after 10 minutes :-)

Comment: Yes, eliminating the sort step by using an index will definitely make the query run a lot faster. I have prototyped an additional version of `COLLECT` that won't require sorted input and use a hash table internally. It looks promising quite so far, but it is not yet ready.

Answer (score 1):

Since ArangoDB 2.6, the `COLLECT` can run in two modes:

- the *sorted* mode that uses a sort step before aggregation
- a *hash table* mode that does not require an upfront sort step

The optimizer will choose the *hash table* mode automatically if it is considered to be cheaper than the *sorted* mode with the sort step.

The new `COLLECT` implementation in 2.6 should make the selection part of the query run much faster in 2.6 than in 2.5 and before. Note that `COLLECT` still produces a sorted output of its **result** (not its input) even with the *hash table* mode. This is done for compatibility with the *sorted* mode. This result sort step can be avoided by adding an extra `SORT null` instruction after the `COLLECT` statement. The optimizer can then optimize away the sorting of the result.

A blog post that explains the two modes is here:
http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2015/04/22/collecting-with-a-hash-table/